# Unable to import NHunspell.dll using ctypes in Python

Tags: python-2.7, ctypes, hunspell, nhunspell

I'm required to import a certain dll called `'NHunspell.dll'` which is used for Spell Checking purposes. I am using **Python** for the software. 
Although I checked out several websites to properly use `ctypes`, I have been unable to load the dll properly.

When I use this code.

```
  from ctypes import *
  hunspell = cdll.LoadLibrary['NHunspell.dll']
```

I get an error

```
  hunspell = cdll.LoadLibrary['NHunspell.dll']
  TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I guess it might a problem with the structure of the dll. But I have no idea how to import the dll properly.

Comment: `LoadLibrary` is a function so try `hunspell = cdll.LoadLibrary('NHunspell.dll')`

Comment: `cdll` is designed for use on Windows, where you can just use `cdll.nhunspell`. On other platforms, use `CDLL(...)`. Also, [NHunspell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhunspell/files) is .NET; it won't have exported symbols for use with ctypes. You could use the C API for [Hunspell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files/Hunspell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @eryksun . But it still did not work. I instead used a Python wrapper for Hunspell called *Pyhunspell*. The actual link in PyPi does not work for Python 2.7 but it has been improved and upgraded in [here](https://github.com/akshaylb/nepali-spellchecker-v2/tree/master/pyhunspell).

Comment: Link in this answer is dead. pyhunspell moved a lot since then too. Here is the new link : https://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell.